# linux listar archivos que empiecen y acaben por X

Tags: linux

Tengo un directorio con cinco archivos llamados:

```
archivo1
archivo2
archivo3
ejemplo2
ejemplo3
```

y quiero mostrar por pantalla y copiar los que empiecen por "ar" y los que acaben en "2" a otro directorio, pero **no** me los encuentra la llamada :

```
ls ar* *2 carpeta/archivos
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp ar*2 otro_directorio
```

Tu ejemplo tiene un error. `ar*` te traerá todos los archivos que comiencen por "ar". `*2` traerá todos los ficheros que terminen en 2. `ar*2` traerá todos los ficheros que comiencen por ar y terminen en 2.